# Haskell: Types don't match

Tags: haskell, signature

I just tried to write a simple function to calculate the average of the input-Ints:

```
avg :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
avg x y z = (x+y+z)/3
```

When I exchange the signature to

```
avg :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
```

it works fine, but with the one above I get the following error message:

Couldn't match expected type 'Float' with actual type 'Int'.

Which possibilites do I have to use the first signature, which accepts Ints (only)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `fromIntegral` to convert the `Int`s to `Float`s:

```
avg :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
avg x y z = (fromIntegral x + fromIntegral y + fromIntegral z) / 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Shorter:

```
avg :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Float
avg x y z = (fromIntegral $ sum [x,y,z]) / 3.0
```

Or you generalize this for a list of `Int`s:

```
avg :: [Int] -> Float
avg xs = (fromIntegral $ sum xs) / (fromIntegral $ length xs)
```

Comment: Isn’t `x+y+z` shorter than `sum [x,y,z]`?

Comment: No, but `fromIntegral $ sum [x,y,z]` is shorter than `fromIntegral x + fromIntegral y + fromIntegral z`. And it is easier to generalize...

Comment: You are answering something different from what I asked.